# How to upgrade codeigniter from version 1.0 to current version?

Tags: codeigniter

How to upgrade codeigniter from version 1.0 to recent version?
I have downloaded the recent version of codeigniter and have a sample project which is written in version 1.0. When i try to run it. I am receiving various kinds of errors for using deprecated functions.

Comment: i thought it would be better to rewrite it since there is many changes since 1.0 to current version which is 2.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to go through http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/upgrading.html and make appropriate changes.

Alternatively, you can just battle the errors as they come up until they're all gone.

It might be easier to just re-write the thing.

Comment: Iam just looking for some medium sized sample projects to learn the flow, can you please give some links which is written in current version, i tried google and i am either getting very simple or older version projects.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/index.html CI has one of the best user guides out there (IMO) - shouldn't need much more than that. If you come across a specific issue the user guide doesn't cover, come back and ask a question here. I don't know of any medium-sized sample projects.